# What's wrorng with this query?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, apex

```
CREATE TABLE informacoes_concurso_publico (
  id_concurso_publico INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  forma_exame VARCHAR(50),
  vagas_totais INTEGER,
  vagas_ampla_concorrencia INTEGER,
  vagas_pcd INTEGER,
  tem_prova_titulos BOOLEAN,
  FOREIGN KEY (id_concurso_publico) REFERENCES concursos_publicos(id_concurso_publico)
);
```

Apex SQL Workshop keep saying that there is a "invalid datatype"

I expect to be able to submit the table without changing its structure

Comment: If your database is Oracle, then tag it thus. Search "oracle create table" and you'll discover which data types are legal. Assuming, of course, that your db is truly Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

There is no type boolean in oracle

```
tem_prova_titulos BOOLEAN,
```

Change that line.